# Azure Preview Portal reporting error configuring storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to use the Azure Preview.  When I try to configure my storage account I receive the following error:

`Monitoring Failure: The server encountered an error while retrieving the metric selection. Retry the operation.`

This has been occurring since yesterday.  I see the error on both ie10 and Chrome.
I tried to create a new storage account and see the same error.
When I run the app the application fails to connect to the storage account with the following error (from node.js):
`Config: C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mychild\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot
Creating Blob Service profile
Creating Blob ...
Fail.{"code":"EACCES","errno":"EACCES","syscall":"connect"}`

Answer (score 0):

As you're not the only one seeing this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925453/the-server-encountered-an-error-while-retrieving-metrics-no-dashboard-metrics/11926777) (myself included), I don't think this is anything to do with what you've done.  I suspect that this is a general problem that Microsoft are having.  I'd recommend logging a support call with the Azure support team if you need this problem resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I did this and a MS support person called me.  They raised the ticket and then archived it because the portal is still classified as being in beta and not covered by support (by the Wipro team).