# The server encountered an error while retrieving metrics - No dashboard metrics in Azure Ubuntu VM

Tags: azure, squid

I'm getting this error: "The server encountered an error while retrieving metrics. Retry the operation." in the dashboard and no Usage overview stats displayed after I've installed and removed a squid proxy server inside an Azure Ubuntu 12.04 server VM.

Anyone know any way to restore them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is related to anything that you've done, I think that MS have having some issues with metrics as I'm getting the same message on instances that I haven't changed.

If it's important for you I would log an issue with MS support.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same error as you. My service instances ran smoothly before this error showed up. And the service instances seem to be still running smoothly even with this error. Only that I cannot get statistics about the instances. It's kind of understandable, since Azure is only CTP now. But I really hops MS will fix this soon.

Comment: issue solved, by MS. I did nothing and the error just disppeared.